# Spring data JPA running multiple single select-by-id queries even after executing join query

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two models Record and RecordException. Their relationship is one to many.
Models are as below

Record ==>

```
@Entity
@IdClass(RecordKey.class)
public class Record implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "RECORDID")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private String recordId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "RECORDID_TYPE")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private String recordIdType;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "RECORDVERSION")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private int recordVersion;

    private String eventName;

    ......

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "RECORDID", referencedColumnName = "RECORDID"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "RECORDID_TYPE", referencedColumnName = "RECORDID_TYPE"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "RECORDVERSION", referencedColumnName = "RECORDVERSION")}
    )
    List<RecordException> exceptions;

}
```

RecordException ===>

```
@Entity
public class RecordException {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "EXCEPTION_ID")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private String exceptionId;

    @Column(name = "RECORDID")
    private String recordId;
    @Column(name = "RECORDID_TYPE")
    private String recordIdType;
    @Column(name = "RECORDVERSION")
    private int recordVersion;
    private String description;
    @Column(name = "EXCEPTION_ENTITY")
    private String exceptionEntity;
    @Column(name = "EXCEPTION_VALUE")
    private String exceptionValue;
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "EXCEPTION_DATETIME")
    private Timestamp exceptionTimestamp;
}
```

To fetch all exceptions associated with a record I wrote a join query like so in a custom repository

```
public interface CustomRecordRepository {
    @Query(value = "SELECT r, re FROM Recordt join RecordException re ON r.recordId=re.recordId and r.recordIdType=re.recordIdType and r.recordVersion=re.recordVersion")
    Set<Record> getRecordsAndExceptions();
}
```

Despite of this in the logs I can see below

```
select
        record0_.recordid as recordid1_4_0_,
        record0_.recordid_type as recordid_2_4_0_,
        record0_.recordversion as recordver3_4_0_,
        recordexcep1_.exception_id as exceptio1_5_1_,
        record0_.event_name as event_na7_4_0_,
        record0_.record_datetime as record_d10_4_0_,
        recordexcep1_.description as descript2_5_1_,
        recordexcep1_.exception_entity as exceptio3_5_1_,
        recordexcep1_.exception_datetime as exceptio4_5_1_,
        recordexcep1_.exception_value as exceptio5_5_1_,
        recordexcep1_.status as status6_5_1_,
        recordexcep1_.recordid as recordid7_5_1_,
        recordexcep1_.recordid_type as recordid_8_5_1_,
        recordexcep1_.recordversion as recordver9_5_1_ 
    from
        record record0_ 
    inner join
        record_exception recordexcep1_ 
            on (
                record0_.recordid=recordexcep1_.recordid 
                and record0_.recordid_type=recordexcep1_.recordid_type 
                and record0_.recordversion=recordexcep1_.recordversion
            )
```

After above query is hit I below queries too

```
select
        exceptions0_.recordid as recordid7_5_0_,
        exceptions0_.recordid_type as recordid_8_5_0_,
        exceptions0_.recordversion as recordver9_5_0_,
        exceptions0_.exception_id as exceptio1_5_0_,
        exceptions0_.exception_id as exceptio1_5_1_,
        exceptions0_.description as descript2_5_1_,
        exceptions0_.exception_entity as exceptio3_5_1_,
        exceptions0_.exception_datetime as exceptio4_5_1_,
        exceptions0_.exception_value as exceptio5_5_1_,
        exceptions0_.status as status6_5_1_,
        exceptions0_.recordid as recordid7_5_1_,
        exceptions0_.recordid_type as recordid_8_5_1_,
        exceptions0_.recordversion as recordver9_5_1_ 
    from
        record_exception exceptions0_ 
    where
        exceptions0_.recordid=? 
        and exceptions0_.recordid_type=? 
        and exceptions0_.recordversion=?
```

Means even after telling hibernate to fetch my data using join I specified it is still using single find-by-id queries on top of that.

What am I doing wrong here? Please help.

Comment: You you select both tables, if you only want to return a `Set<Records>`. In this case you should only select the values from the records table -->`SELECT r FROM ...`.  I'm not 100% sure, but i guess hibernate will do 2 queries, because it can not covert the result of both tables to the `Record` object

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a [fetch join](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.0/jakarta-persistence-spec-3.0.html#a4931) to fetch the associated elements. Ie

```
@Query(value = "SELECT r FROM Record r join fetch r.exceptions")
```

And the join conditions should work without being explicit about them...